# How to get RDLC report render PDF with ToUnicode entry for copypasting non-ansi text from the resulting PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, reporting, rdlc

Preface: we have a reports generated in c# application using [Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms. LocalReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.aspx) class from a RDLC file. They are rendered in PDF format. The text in the report is mostly in Cyrillics. The problem is: it's impossible to copy it from the resulting PDF file, you get garbage.

The reason you get garbage is the text is written as the "Identity-H" encoding for the font. It's not a real encoding, it's just an assignment of CIDs (basically, numbers) for glyphs used in the PDF file. [Adobe's PDF format has the "ToUnicode"](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/5411.ToUnicode.pdf) entry for this reason – that's what should store the correspondence of CIDs to the Unicode characters. If this information was present, it would be possible to copy/past text from the file correctly.

Obviously, this class doesn't write it. While researching the problem, I came across [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/07/01/export-reports-to-pdf-with-improved-support-for-international-text/) that recognizes the lack of copy/paste support and praises it finally being implemented... in SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services.

Well, we don't use ServerReport class and SQL Server RS. Or SQL Server 2016. It'll be kinda a weird and way too giant architectural changes to move to it just because managers complain they cannot copy text from PDFs.

So, is there a workaround? I doubt noone faced this problem before. Maybe the writing of this ToUnicode entry was implemented in LocalReport in the newer version of dotNet? Did someone write some sort of wrapper classes that take a bytearray of the PDF and enhance it? Or maybe people render the report to DOCX and then use some other library to make a PDF out of that correctly?